# How to Convert Storyboard App to SwiftUI App

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, storyboard

I'm looking to rebuild my storyboard app in SwiftUI. I'm fine rewriting the UI but I want it to be under the same App Store listing and with the same entitlements, etc. Is there an easy way to switch the project from storyboard to SwiftUI, or to create a new app under the same app store listing?

Comment: As long as you submit an app with the same bundle and team ID, it’ll be considered the same app in the store.

Comment: I went through both processes: converting in place (screen by screen) and having a new project and moving relevant parts from old project to new. Both ways work, as long as as said above you don't change bundle ID and are signing with the cert/profile from the same Apple account. The advantage of doing in-place change is that you can release in mixed mode (while some screens are still UIKit). Starting new project allows you to reset the whole structure to latest format, so you don't need to later migrate project itself (build settings, things like AppDelegate and so on).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your tips @timbretimbre!  Do you have any tips for conversion/"mixed mode"?

Comment: 1 - make sure you have a good separation between functionality and UI and/or unit testing for functionality. That will allow you to minimize the chance that you are breaking the feature when converting. It's often small things: someone did the conversion from unit A to unit B directly in UI components... or error handling for networking request done directly on UI level. So a some refactoring for a screen you are converting may be in order

Comment: 2 - Look through your screens and identify 3 groups of screens: easy to convert = screens with static data, forms (e.g. login) - they are usually just a straight forward conversion; medium level of difficulty = lists, collections. These may require you to rething an approach to use all the features SwiftUI allows. They generally have a different flow than UIKit, but also you may find that using the new Concurrency or Combine frameworks significantly simplifies them.

Comment: And finally difficult ones = anything to do with custom graphics. These sometimes may need a different approach (like lists), or sometimes you won't yet have SwiftUI analogue (yet), so you may need to just wrap UIKit components to use in SwiftUI. In any case I found those to be the least easy to convert.

3 - If your app is heavy on accessibility, generally you can rely on SwiftUI accessibility to be much better already with defaults, but there are gotchas, so you have to test it for every screen.